# index operator in handlebars say Unexpected token ,

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have #each loop in my ember app and want to know index of loop, so I try to using {{@index}} like this :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="column">
<ul>
{{#each item in controller}}
{{@index}}
{{item-rows currentItem=item}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

But in chrome, I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , handlebars.js:1457
```

My ember.js version is rc8 and handlebars is 1. I need a solution to find index of #each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the contentIndex from `itemViewClass` of the `#each` helper

```
{{#each itemViewClass="Em.View"}}
   <h3 class="row">{{name}} - <small>{{view.contentIndex}}</small></h3>    
{{/each}}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/jwEYk/3/)

Comment: Any idea why Handlebars when used with Ember causes this? According to the Handlebars home page `@index` should work just fine. Why does Ember break this?

Comment: @Sukima AFAIK, Ember doesn't use the handlebars helpers. Ember has built its own helpers for `each`, `if` and so on ...